# $\lim_ {n \to \infty} f_n$ is $\Sigma$-measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space and let $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of $\Sigma$-measurable  real valued functions with domains included in $X$.

> What does it mean to say "domains included in $X$"? Why is this significant?

We define a function $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n$ by writing

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (f_n)(x) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n (x)$$

for $x \in \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \cap_{m \geq n} \text{dom } f_m$ for which the limit exists in $\mathbb{R}$.

Then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n$  is $\Sigma$-measurable.

> What does $x \in \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \cap_{m \geq n}\text{dom } f_m$ mean? How can it be interpreted?

Comment: For "domains included in $X$", as far as I can see this is redundant since $f_n^{-1} (\mathbb{R}) \in \Sigma$ and surely $f_n^{-1}(\mathbb{R})\subset X$

Comment: There is a special command to typeset the limit: `\lim_{ ... }`. Also `\sum` gives a large $\sum$, while `\Sigma` gives a normal sized $\Sigma$.

Answer (score 1):

The set

$$\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \cap_{m \geq n}\hbox{dom}f_m$$

consists of precisely those elements of $X$ where $f_m(x)$ is well-defined from a certain value of $m$ onwards. That is the condition you need to impose on $x$ to be able to even *define* the concept of $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x).$